# I Want that 404 not found back in case of "Invalid controller specified"

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

In my zend framework 1 project i have an `.htaccess` file which would redirect everything which is not a file to the `index.php` this is the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

As a result every irelevent request would end at `index.php` and, the error `Invalid controller specified` and the page seems so buggy. I want that 404 page not found back when there is an invalid request. this is my config file

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
autoMailUser = info@listab.ir
autoMailPassword = 
autoMailHost = mail.listab.ir
emailes = ""
searchIndexPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/SearchIndex"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/"
resources.layout.layout = master

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "listab_"
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://root:@localhost/mylistab"

host = localhost
username = root
password = 
dbname = mylistab

resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = mylistab
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8;"

resources.router.routes.useraddpage.route =/p/:user/:page
resources.router.routes.useraddpage.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.useraddpage.defaults.controller = book
resources.router.routes.useraddpage.defaults.action = vitrin

resources.router.routes.useradd.route =/p/:user
resources.router.routes.useradd.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.useradd.defaults.controller = book
resources.router.routes.useradd.defaults.action = vitrin

resources.router.routes.bookview.route =/book/view/:id/:page
resources.router.routes.bookview.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.bookview.defaults.controller = book
resources.router.routes.bookview.defaults.action = view

resources.router.routes.bookviewc.route =/book/viewcomments/:id/:page
resources.router.routes.bookviewc.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.bookviewc.defaults.controller = book
resources.router.routes.bookviewc.defaults.action = viewcomments

resources.router.routes.bookc.route =/book/buyconfirm/:id
resources.router.routes.bookc.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.bookc.defaults.controller = book
resources.router.routes.bookc.defaults.action = buyconfirm

resources.router.routes.bookbuy.route =/book/buy/:code
resources.router.routes.bookbuy.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.bookbuy.defaults.controller = book
resources.router.routes.bookbuy.defaults.action = buy

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production, you probably want:

```
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
```

That will give you the more user-friendly 404 page instead of the "Invalid controller specified" exception.